# Search for user-given char in String array

Tags: java, search, methods, contains

My project is a personal-management program which has three arrays (1 for the surname one, 1 for name and 1 for the address of the employee). The program should be able to serve the purpose of management that's why it has a couple of functions (add new employees, search for employees by index position etc…). This is my last method which should be able to go through the employees and find the name which contains xx (the letters entered by the user, as he doesn't remember the name properly) and print out the address (adres) the surname(nN) and the name(vN) of the worker.

Till now two methods have i implemented to achieve my goal, none of them worked properly:

1st:

```
public static void sucheXL(String[] vN, String[] nN, String[] adres) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Text ein: ");
        String nn = sc.nextLine();
        boolean gefunden = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(nN).contains(nn)) {
                System.out.println("Dieser Name " + nN[i] + " fängt mit " + nn + " an");
                gefunden = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!gefunden) {
                System.out.println("Es wurden keine Namen gefunden, die diesen Text beinhalten");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

2nd:

```
public static void sucheL(String[] vN, String[] nN, String[] adres) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Text ein: ");
        String nn = sc.nextLine();
        boolean gefunden = nN.contains(nn);
        for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {
            if (gefunden == true) {
                System.out.println("Dieser Name " + nN[i] + " fängt mit " + nn + " an");
                gefunden = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!gefunden) {
                System.out.println("Es wurden keine Namen gefunden, die diesen Text beinhalten");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are checking if `nN` contains an entry that equals the given char sequence, but that would only match full first or last names. Check if each entry contains or starts with (those are different!) the entered sequence. `String` has the methods `startsWith(String)` and `contains(String)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the entries (names) for full equality to the text entered, which seems undesired...

If you want to find out if any entry either starts with the text entered or contains it, you will have to find out if the name actually contains the character sequence from `System.in`. You can do it like this:

```
public static void sucheXL(String[] nN) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Geben Sie den Text ein: ");
    String nn = sc.nextLine();

    // you may want to close the Scanner...
    sc.close();

    boolean gefunden = false;

    // check for all the entries in nN
    for (int i = 0; i < nN.length; i++) {

        // if the entry starts with the entered String or
        if (nN[i].startsWith(nn)) {
            System.out.println("Der Name " + nN[i] + " beginnt mit " + nn);
            gefunden = true;
            break;
        // if it contains the entered String
        } else if (nN[i].contains(nn)) {
            System.out.println("Der Name " + nN[i] + " enthält " + nn);
            gefunden = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!gefunden) {
        System.err.println("Es wurde kein Name gefunden, der mit dem eingegebenen Text beginnt oder ihn beinhaltet");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Es wurde mindestens ein Name gefunden, der mit dem eingegebenen Text beginnt oder ihn beinhaltet");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a `main` with some example `String[]` somehow like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Hans", "Fritz", "Horst", "Rudolf", "Jürgen", "Dietmar", "Jwan"};
    sucheXL(names);
}
```

Entering `"or"` gives me the result

```
Geben Sie den Text ein: 
or
Der Name Horst enthält or
Es wurde mindestens ein Name gefunden, der mit dem eingegebenen Text beginnt oder ihn beinhaltet
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and your code let me understand java a bit more, but when i run the method in the switch method (which is number 6) i get the following `error on the console :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PersonalVerwaltung.sucheL(PersonalVerwaltung.java:146)
 at PersonalVerwaltung.main(PersonalVerwaltung.java:52)`

although there is no red light marked code lines in IntelliJ